# Excel VBA: Run macro when cell value changes

Tags: vba, excel

I cannot get the macro to run when the cell value changes. My code is below:

This is placed in the sheet's module:

```
Sub HideRow()

    Dim beginRow As Long, endRow As Long, chkCol As Long, chkCommCol As Long
    Dim rowCnt As Long, HiddenRow As Long

beginRow = 1
endRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '<--| set 'endRow' to column A 
last not empty cell row index
chkCol = 1
chkCommCol = 5
HiddenCol = 8

Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'unhides all rows. Subsequent code will hide 
relevant ones

    If Cells(1, chkCommCol).Value = "White Base" Then '<--| if E1 value is 
                  "White Base"
       Cells(HiddenCol, chkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If


End Sub
```

This is placed in the general workbook section:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Cells(1, chkCommCol) Then HideRow '<--| if "E1" cell 
           has been changed then run 'HideRow' macro
End Sub
```

Comment: General workbook section?  `Worksheet_Change` event codes need to be hosted in the specific worksheet's module.  If you're using the ThisWorkbook module, the event is `Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` and as you can see it specifies which sheet the change occurred on in addition to the Target cell(s).  Also, your `chkCommCol` variable is not a public variable, so there's no way for your `Worksheet_Change` code to know its value.

Comment: Basically, instead of calling another macro, it looks like you just want to do this in your change event (and make sure the event is hosted in the specific sheet module, not the ThisWorkbook module): `If Target.Address = "$E$1" Then Range("A8").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "White Base")`